# Strange setAttribute behavior in IE8 after Object extend

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code that I'm using to create a micro-library of sorts (similar to JQuery, but with only the stuff I need).

```
window.$ = function(selector, context, undefined) 
{
    var getSelectorTest = function(selector, context, undefined)
    {
        var el;
        var selector_key = selector.slice(0, 1),
            matches = {
                '#': 'getElementById',
                '.': 'getElementsByClassName',
                '@': 'getElementsByName',
                '=': 'getElementsByTagName',
                '*': 'querySelectorAll'
            }[selector_key],
            selector_value = selector.slice(1);

        //add fallback for getElementsByClassName is not supported e.g. IE8
        if(matches === 'getElementsByClassName' && !document.getElementsByClassName)
        {
            matches = 'querySelectorAll';
            selector_value = selector;
        }

        // now pass the selector without the key/first character
        el = (((context === undefined) ? document: context)[matches](selector_value));
        return el;
    };

    var elem = getSelectorTest(selector, context, undefined);

    //Extend elem before returning it
    elem.attr = function(name, value) {
    if(value)
    {
        this.setAttribute(name, value);
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.getAttribute(name);
    }   

    return elem;
};
```

Then when I run the following code:

```
<script>
    domReady(function(){ //https://github.com/cms/domready
        var el_1 = $('#container-1');
        el_1.attr("data-test", "random_value");
    });
</script>
```

I get the following when using IE8:

```
<div id="container-1" attr="function(name, value) {
            if(value)
                {
                    this.setAttribute(name, value);
                    return this;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.getAttribute(name);
                }

        }" data-test="random_value">
```

Of course, this isn't the case when I use Chrome and Firefox (I get the output as expected i.e. `<div id="container-1" data-test="random_value">`). How can I fix this?

Note: I'm using 'HTML' tab of the IE8 Developer Tools (F12) to verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching the `attr()` function to the selected element (which IE8 apparently interprets as setting an attribute on the element itself) you might have better luck attaching it to the prototype of the `Element` object.

```
Element.prototype.attr = function(name,value){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `HTMLElement.prototype.attr` didn't work, but `Element.prototype.attr` did. Could you update the answer?